# RESTEasy response with multiple elements with location link

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

We have implemented "get-single-entity" part of API like that:

```
Object entity = ...
final URI terminate = ...
Response
        .status(201)
        .entity(entity)
        .link(terminate, "terminate")
        .build();
```

After receiving response user can click the terminate link to terminate this entity.

Now we want to implement API that allows users to retrieve all of the entities.

Is there a way to create a response with a list of entities so that every entity has this terminate link with it?

Comment: What do you mean by _terminate_?

Comment: When you say Link, do you mean location?

Comment: this terminate link is basically the same thing as location